# PyEnchant: adapt folder for Win-32bit and Win-64bit

Tags: python, pyenchant

I use PyEnchant library from PyPI site.
I got Windows 32 bit release: it loads OK on Win-32, Linux, macOS; but doesn't work on Windows 64 bit (it's OK: DLLs are 32 bit).

- iconv.dll
- intl.dll
- libenchant-1.dll
- libglib-2.0-0.dll
- libgmodule-2.0-0.dll
- lib/enchant/lib*.dll (2 files)

I tried to have 2 copies of pyenchant: one in dir win32, other in win64; and added one of directories/folders to `sys.path`. So these are 2 directories/folders and hard for users to copy spell-dict's inside these 2 directories/folders.

I want to use it in a cross-platform app. So need one directory/folder "pyenchant".
How to change lib, place 32-bit/64-bit DLLs, so that one "pyenchant" directory/folder can be used in both Win-32 and Win-64? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to make Windows search for your DLLs on the path you specify. You will need to add your dlls to Windows' `PATH` variable; plase take a look at
[DLL - How to put a folder on PATH with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/214868/679240); you will have to detect whether you are on a 32 or 64 bit system, and dynamically configure the `PATH` as necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I need DLLs inside "pyenchant", app should not put smth to Windows sys folders.

Comment: Okay, I think I misundestood the question.

Comment: PATH will not work, seems, coz PyEnchant loads DLLs from absolute path.